# About organizing controllers with inherited resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, inheritance

As I understood IR(inherited resources) inherits from ApplicationController. That's ok. In current scheme I have profile controller, which is the base for other profile controllers (projects, portfolio, reviews, etc.). So every profile controller looks like

```
class Profile::ReviewsController < Profile::ProfileController
  def index
  end
end
```

The goal is to implement IR to this scheme. There are some problems:

- I can't inherits profile controllers from IR, because in that case I missed some logic from main **ProfileController**
- Write *inherit_resources* in every controller looks stupid and not rails way.

When I trying to inherit main ProfileController from IR::Base there are problems with collection and resource. There are everything created from Profile model.

So how to organize it wright?